# Refreshing a Today extension view

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios8, ios8-today-widget

I created a today extension for my iOS App. My app is fetching new datas in background and saving it into a shared database in the app group.

How I can make (if it's possible) the extension to update it's view when background fetches of the main app are performed ? If it's not possible, how I can make something equivalent (like regularly updating the extension to check for new datas in the shared database).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use shared NSUserDefaults and observer it.

**In your app**:

After you update database, execute the below:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.yourcompany.sharedDefaults"];
[userDefaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"updatedDate"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

**In your Today Widget:**

add a observer in viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(userDefaultsDidChange:)
                                             name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

then

```
- (void)userDefaultsDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // check updatedDate and update widget UI
}
```

refer: http://www.glimsoft.com/06/28/ios-8-today-extension-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks ! I saw this tutorial but not the interesting part for me... Shame on me !!!

Comment: Doesn't the addObserver method get called too many times? each time the viewDidLoad is invoked, without ever dismissing the observer?

Comment: The viewDidLoad get called only once. And you need to remove observer in the dealloc method.

Comment: According to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26523460/today-extension-view-flashes-when-redrawing the viewDidLoad function gets called every time the user pulls the widget drawer. Does the system also create a new instance of the widget? or only recomputes the view?

Comment: Create a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

The system create the ViewController every time, but your singleton-instance in your today widget code keep living during a long period.