# Today Widget tableView freezes

Tags: ios, swift, widget, tableview, today-extension

I have a today widget that contains two things:

1. A `UILabel`
2. A `UITableView`

In my `viewWillAppear`I set the label to be visible and my tableView to be hidden and I set the label text to "Loading". See image below.

[image]

Then I get a location and when this is done, I call another method and

1. If I do not find any data I just update the label text to "Did not find data"
2. Otherwise I set the label to be hidden and the tableView to be visible and I start updating the data

When this is successfully done I have a tableView that looks like this:

[image].

**To my issue now.**
 When I open my today widget and hit `viewWillAppear`, I don´t always manage to set my label and the only result I get is this

[image].

So what happens is that I can only show a bit of my previous result in the tableView.

This happens occasionally and it seems that the tableView freezes and I´m not able to update the initial view, to hide the tableView and show the label instead. Even when the screen freezes like this everything is running like it should and I manage to update the tableView and the view.

The only issue is when I open the widget that the screen freezes like this:

[image]

sometimes instead of showing my label. The reason it´s in the size as it is, is because I set the `preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 30)`. Otherwise I bet it will have shown the entire previous tableView.

Any ideas of how to solve this, to always update the view when I hit `viewWillAppear`?

**Update**
Starting another bounty to see if there is some other input on this issue.

Comment: Can you add some code, for example do you make network request and then parse the result ? If yes, do you `reload()` table view ? and hide label. If you add some of the implementation maybe i can help you

Comment: Please show us the code, it’s not possible to help otherwise!

Comment: Are you conforming to the `NCWidgetProviding` protocol and implementing `widgetMarginInsetsForProposedMarginInsets:` already?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**What the system does is that it takes a Snapshot.** I have also been struggling a bit with this issue and I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26523460/today-extension-view-flashes-when-redrawing) post but it did not solve my issue.

For the `widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler` there are three options

1. `NCUpdateResultNewData` — The new content required you to redraw the view
2. `NCUpdateResultNoData` — The widget doesn’t require updating
3. `NCUpdateResultFailed` — An error occurred during the update process

It does not matter which one of these is called it´s always the same result. **And the system does take a Snapshot.**

> To help your widget look up to date, the system occasionally captures
>   snapshots of your widget’s view. When the widget becomes visible
>   again, the most recent snapshot is displayed until the system replaces
>   it with a live version of the view.
>
> To update a widget’s state before a snapshot is taken, be sure to
>   conform to the NCWidgetProviding protocol. When your widget receives
>   the widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler: call, update your
>   widget’s view with the most recent content and call the completion
>   handler, using one of the following constants to describe the result
>   of the update

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/NotificationCenter.html).

I think that we´re maybe trying to load to "heavy" data and this could occur because of that. This is my answer, but I started a bounty to check if someone else has another answer or if you agree with my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your operation in `viewdidload()`, because `viewdidload()` will be called when you enter you widget.